# keydown in objective-C 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keydown, nsevent

[UPDATED AFTER FIRST AWNSER]
I have tried to find a way to use and implement the keyDown option in Objective C. But when I try it, it always fails...

Can anyone give me an example of how this is done. I understand Objective C good and a full explaination is not needed.

I deleted the method in `-(void) keyDown` because it wasn't working.

This is my code now:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ViewController : NSView {
    IBOutlet id pressLabel;
}

@end



#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL) becomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL) resignFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString *theUpArrow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",NSUpArrowFunctionKey];
    if( [[theEvent characters] isEqualToString:theUpArrow]){
        [pressLabel setStringValue:@"Pressed"];
    } else {
        [super keyDown:theEvent];   
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 7):

`keyDown:` is an NSResponder method, typically implemented in views. This class is named Controller, which would suggest it isn't a view, and thus won't receive key down events. You probably want to put it in a view instead.

Comment: @Muttur: What Chuck said. Take a look at the [Responder Chain Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2) to understand why this object is not getting `keyDown:` called on it.

Comment: I updated my post with the classes I have now. But it still doesn't work... What's wrong?

Comment: You’ve added some support for being able to become first responder but you’re not actually in the chain. Take a look at `-[NSResponder setNextResponder:]`.

Comment: @Ben I can't figure it out... Help please :s

Answer (score 1):

```
    [self keyDown:theEvent];
```

This doesn't solve your problem, but I think for the line above, you want to use `super` and not `self`. If you use `self` it will invoke the same method again, and it will keep invoking the same method over and over, eventually crashing your application once there is no more stack space.

Comment: With super it doesnt work to :s I updated it again but is it possible you can make me a project or something? I'm pretty desperate and I was working a week on this before I posted it here.

Comment: @Muttur: There's nothing wrong with the `keyDown:` method itself. Your problem is that your object isn't in the Responder Chain. Read the doc that I linked to below, or read [this explanation](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/bit-about-responder-chain.html) and look at the [NSResponder class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as Ben suggested. This is the piece you're missing.

Comment: @Josh this isn't about iPhone development and I can't figure out how the NSResponder link's to my NSEvent. Do I need to use another class? Because I read some thing about NSTextView/NSTextField. Is this needed?

Comment: @Muttur: The responder chain works the same on the iPhone as it does on the Mac. You don't create `NSEvent`s yourself; the system creates one when the user presses a key. The system passes the event to your app, which passes it to objects in the chain. Your object needs to be in the chain to get events. The best way to make sure of that is to make your object a view -- an visible object in the interface.  Use Interface Builder to put a "custom view" in your window, then change the class of that view to this class that you've written.